# How should I give ForeignKey to model?

Tags: python, django

How should I give ForeignKey to model?
Now models.py has User&Item table like

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    regist_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Item(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I wanna treat user_id&name_id as Foreing key.User table is parent table,and Item is child one.I think user_id&name_id in Item should have ForeignKey like

```
class Item(models.Model):
        user_id = models.ForeignKey()
        name = models.ForeignKey()
```

However,how should I connect these 2 model is User is parent&Item is child ?How should I write it?

Comment: Don't write code, just tell the logic what you need.

Answer (score 1):

For sure, you have to read [that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#relationships).

Looks like One User -> Many Items.
Its ForeignKey and we have to set it in User model.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    ...

class User(models.Model):
    ...
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='items')
```

Accessing user_id from item will be

```
item.user.user_id
```

Accessing all items from a user will be

```
user.items.all()
```

Comment: thx, ur comments.I wrote
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    regist_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='items')
    item.user.user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item.user.name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=200

Comment: but Unresolved reference 'item' error happens.Am I wrong to understand ur answer?How can I fix this?

Comment: You don’t need to define the user_id property again inside Item. Once the foreign key is defined, you can get the user_id by doing, item.user.user_id where item is an instance of the Item model

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to read the documentation on the [`ForeignKey` field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey).

As for your question, you can connect the Item model to the User model like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Again, it's a good idea to read the documentation and figure out what exactly you need, such as what to do when a `User` object is deleted (the `on_delete` part in my code).